# Build template based on variables of other hosts

Tags: ansible

I want to build a template which differs for each host.
Assume these four hosts with the following variables:

```yaml
# host_1 host_vars
my:
  info:
    - name: one
    - name: two
    
# host_2 host_vars
my:
  info:
    - name: two
    - name: three

# host_3 host_vars
my:
  info:
    - name: one
    - name: three

# host_4 host_vars
my:
  info:
    - name: whatever
```

The result of the template should be:

```yaml
# for host_1
one host_1 host_3
two host_1 host_2

# for host_2
two host_2 host_1
three host_2 host_3

# for host_3
one host_3 host_1
three host_3 host_2

# for host_4
whatever host_4
```

My question is: I want to keep the configuration simple.
Where should I build this logic?
Should I share facts among hosts during Ansible runtime and then template it?  Or is there a solution to build this easily during templating already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can access the variables of other hosts with the help of the special variable [`hostvars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-hostvars), you can definitely template the fact that some variables are also present in another host variables.

An example of template doing so would be:

```
{% for info in my.info %}
  {{- info.name -}}
  {% for host in hostvars
        | dict2items
        | selectattr('value.my.info', 'defined')
     if host.value.my.info
        | selectattr('name', '==', info.name)
  %} {{ host.key }}{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

In this example we are using:

- the filter [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dict2items_filter.html), to make a list of hosts dictionaries out of the dictionary of hosts that is `hostvars`
- the filter [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr), twice, to filter out any host(s) where `my.info` would not be defined, then, filter out other hosts that do not share the same `info.name` as the current host
- a [`for ... if ...`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#for) construct to reject any host not having the same `info[].name` as the current host

---

For example, with the inventory:

```yaml
all:
  children:
    demo:
      hosts:
        host_1:
          ansible_host: ansible-node-1
          my:
            info:
              - name: one
              - name: two
        host_2:
          ansible_host: ansible-node-2
          my:
            info:
              - name: two
              - name: three
        host_3:
          ansible_host: ansible-node-3
          my:
            info:
              - name: one
              - name: three
        host_4:
          ansible_host: ansible-node-4
          my:
            info:
              - name: whatever
```

And the `debug` task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {% for info in my.info %}
        {{- info.name -}}
        {% for host in hostvars
              | dict2items
              | selectattr('value.my.info', 'defined')
           if host.value.my.info
              | selectattr('name', '==', info.name)
        %} {{ host.key }}{% endfor %}

      {% endfor %}
```

We get a result of:

```yaml
ok: [host_4] => 
  msg: |-
    whatever host_4
ok: [host_1] => 
  msg: |-
    one host_1 host_3
    two host_1 host_2
ok: [host_2] => 
  msg: |-
    two host_1 host_2
    three host_2 host_3
ok: [host_3] => 
  msg: |-
    one host_1 host_3
    three host_2 host_3
```

Comment: Dang, that's indeed short, easy and simple to read.

Answer (score 2):

Your description is a bit abstract and I'm not totally sure I get your full requirement. But to me it looks like you are reinventing the wheel.

If I rephrase the above as I get it: you have hosts belonging to groups and you want a template that will, for each group the host belongs to, write a line with the name of the group followed by the current host and then all other members.

Here is a minimal example which achieves that requirement

File structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── inventories
│   └── default
│       └── hosts.yml
├── playbook.yml
└── templates
    └── my_template.j2

3 directories, 3 files
```

Our test `inventories/default/hosts.yml` inventory:

```yaml
---
one:
  hosts:
    host_1:
    host_3:

two:
  hosts:
    host_1:
    host_2:

three:
  hosts:
    host_2:
    host_3:

whatever:
  hosts:
    host_4:
```

The content of `templates/my_template.j2` is:

```
{% for current_group in group_names %}
{% set other_hosts = groups[current_group] | difference([inventory_hostname]) %}
{{ current_group }} {{ inventory_hostname }} {{ other_hosts | join(' ') }}
{% endfor %}
```

And the `playbook.yml` to test that template:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  # This is for test only
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Show result of template
      vars:
        template_result: "{{ lookup('template', 'my_template.j2') }}"
        to_debug_result: "{{ template_result | split('\n') }}"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: to_debug_result
```

gives as a result:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i  inventories/default/ playbook.yml 

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show result of template] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => {
    "to_debug_result": [
        "one host_1 host_3",
        "two host_1 host_2",
        ""
    ]
}
ok: [host_3] => {
    "to_debug_result": [
        "one host_3 host_1",
        "three host_3 host_2",
        ""
    ]
}
ok: [host_2] => {
    "to_debug_result": [
        "three host_2 host_3",
        "two host_2 host_1",
        ""
    ]
}
ok: [host_4] => {
    "to_debug_result": [
        "whatever host_4 ",
        ""
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
host_1                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_2                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_3                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_4                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host_1
host_2
host_3
host_4
```

and the *host_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host_1/my_info.yml 
my:
  info:
    - name: one
    - name: two
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host_2/my_info.yml 
my:
  info:
    - name: two
    - name: three
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host_3/my_info.yml 
my:
  info:
    - name: one
    - name: three
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host_4/my_info.yml 
my:
  info:
    - name: whatever
```

---

Short answer: Create the dictionary

```yaml
name_hosts:
  one: [host_1, host_3]
  three: [host_2, host_3]
  two: [host_1, host_2]
  whatever: [host_4]
```

Then, the template is trivial

```yaml
{% for i in my.info %}
{{ i.name }} {{ name_hosts[i.name]|join(' ') }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

Details: There are more options. Use [Community.General](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_merging_lists_of_dictionaries.html) in the first example. If you can't or don't want to use *Community.General* the second example provides solution with *Ansible.Builtin* functions only.

**Example 1.**

Instantiate lists of hosts and names *my_info*

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      my_info: "{{ my.info|product([{'hosts': [inventory_hostname]}])|
                           map('combine') }}"
  - debug:
      var: my_info|to_yaml
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ************************************************
ok: [host_2] => 
  my_info:
    - hosts: [host_2]
      name: two
    - hosts: [host_2]
      name: three
ok: [host_1] => 
  my_info:
    - hosts: [host_1]
      name: one
    - hosts: [host_1]
      name: two
ok: [host_4] => 
  my_info:
    - hosts: [host_4]
      name: whatever
ok: [host_3] => 
  my_info:
    - hosts: [host_3]
      name: one
    - hosts: [host_3]
      name: three
```

Extract all lists *my_info* and merge the items by *name*

```yaml
  name_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                  map('extract', hostvars, 'my_info')|
                  community.general.lists_mergeby('name', list_merge='append')|
                  items2dict(key_name='name', value_name='hosts') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  name_hosts:
    one: [host_1, host_3]
    three: [host_2, host_3]
    two: [host_1, host_2]
    whatever: [host_4]
```

Create the template

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: |
        {% for i in my.info %}
        {{ i.name }} {{ name_hosts[i.name]|join(' ') }}
        {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ************************************************
ok: [host_1] => 
  msg: |-
    one host_1 host_3
    two host_1 host_2
ok: [host_3] => 
  msg: |-
    one host_1 host_3
    three host_2 host_3
ok: [host_2] => 
  msg: |-
    two host_1 host_2
    three host_2 host_3
ok: [host_4] => 
  msg: |-
    whatever host_4
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    name_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                    map('extract', hostvars, 'my_info')|
                    community.general.lists_mergeby('name', list_merge='append')|
                    items2dict(key_name='name', value_name='hosts') }}"

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        my_info: "{{ my.info|product([{'hosts': [inventory_hostname]}])|
                             map('combine') }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_info|to_yaml

    - debug:
        var: name_hosts|to_yaml
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in my.info %}
          {{ i.name }} {{ name_hosts[i.name]|join(' ') }}
          {% endfor %}
```

---

**Example 2.**

Create a dictionary of all *my.info*

```yaml
  all_info: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                     zip(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                         map('extract', hostvars, ['my', 'info'])|
                         map('map', attribute='name'))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  all_info:
    host_1: [one, two]
    host_2: [two, three]
    host_3: [one, three]
    host_4: [whatever]
```

Create a list of all names

```yaml
  all_names: "{{ all_info.values()|flatten|unique }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  all_names: [one, two, three, whatever]
```

Create a dictionary of all names and hosts

```yaml
  name_hosts: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for name in all_names %}
    {{ name }}: {{ all_info|dict2items|selectattr('value', 'contains', name)|map(attribute='key') }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  name_hosts:
    one: [host_1, host_3]
    three: [host_2, host_3]
    two: [host_1, host_2]
    whatever: [host_4]
```

Now you've got all elements to create the template you want

```yaml
        - debug:
            msg: |
              {% for host,names in all_info.items() %}
              {{ '#' }} for {{ host }}
              {% for name in names %}
              {{ name }} {{ name_hosts[name]|join(' ') }}
              {% endfor %}

              {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    # for host_1
    one host_1 host_3
    two host_1 host_2
  
    # for host_2
    two host_1 host_2
    three host_2 host_3
  
    # for host_3
    one host_1 host_3
    three host_2 host_3
  
    # for host_4
    whatever host_4
```

Optionally, each host can use the template

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in my.info %}
          {{ i.name }} {{ name_hosts[i.name]|join(' ') }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************************************
ok: [host_4] => 
  msg: |-
    whatever host_4
ok: [host_1] => 
  msg: |-
    one host_1 host_3
    two host_1 host_2
ok: [host_2] => 
  msg: |-
    two host_1 host_2
    three host_2 host_3
ok: [host_3] => 
  msg: |-
    one host_1 host_3
    three host_2 host_3
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    all_info: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                       zip(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                           map('extract', hostvars, ['my', 'info'])|
                           map('map', attribute='name'))) }}"
    all_names: "{{ all_info.values()|flatten|unique }}"
    names_hosts: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for tag in all_names %}
      {{ tag }}: {{ all_info|dict2items|selectattr('value', 'contains', tag)|map(attribute='key') }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: all_info|to_yaml
        - debug:
            var: all_names|to_yaml
        - debug:
            var: names_hosts|to_yaml
        - debug:
            msg: |
              {% for host,names in all_info.items() %}
              {{ '#' }} for {{ host }}
              {% for name in names %}
              {{ name }} {{ names_hosts[name]|join(' ') }}
              {% endfor %}

              {% endfor %}
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in my.info %}
          {{ i.name }} {{ names_hosts[i.name]|join(' ') }}
          {% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's really interesting to see how you, and the others, came up w a solution.